# Telerik not showing in intellisense of VS 2008

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, telerik, intellisense, telerik-mvc

I was coding an aspx page to use the telerik grid. But telerik is not showing in intellisense of VS 2008.

Following are the things done so far:
1. Added the telerik dll in the reference folder.

1. Code part

   ```
   <%@ Page Language="C#"  Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage"%>
   ```

   <%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>

   <%@ Import Namespace="Telerik.Web.Mvc" %>

   Index

   ```
       <% foreach(var v in (List<String>)ViewData["names"])
           {

   Response.Write(v);
              %>
              <br />
              <%
           } 


   %>

      <%  Html. %>
   ```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Visual Studio Intellisense in views is far from perfect. Personally what I do is to add the assembly (`<assemblies>` tag) and the namespace (`<namespaces>` tag) in web.config, so that it is available in all views. This way I no longer need to add any Import section in each view. After doing this you probably might need to reopen the view for the changes to take effect. Even restart Visual Studio. If it works at runtime and you don't get Intellisense at compile-time, well, I wish they improve it in future versions.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. But the its still not showing in intellisense. But thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, everything is working fine, except  showing telerik properties in intellisense.